# A and B University

Tags: word-usage, writing-style

Since "A University and B University" is rather long, which of the following might be true and why?

The research job was at A and B University,

The research job was at A and B Universities,

The research job was at A and B universities.

Thank you.

Comment: Good question - but I think it would be clearer if you provided a sentence in which it's being used, and rather than 'A' and 'B' provide real university names ('Oxford' and 'Yale' for example).

Comment: Since they're proper names, you should capitalize University(ies). And the current usage is clearly to [pluralize Universities](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Harvard+and+Yale+College%2CHarvard+and+Yale+Colleges%2COxford+and+Cambridge+Universities%2COxford+and+Cambridge+University&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHarvard%20and%20Yale%20College%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHarvard%20and%20Yale%20Colleges%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COxford%20and%20Cambridge%20Universities%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COxford%20and%20Cambridge%20University%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they're proper names, you should capitalize University(ies).

And the most common current usage is to [pluralize Universities](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Harvard+and+Yale+College%2CHarvard+and+Yale+Colleges%2COxford+and+Cambridge+Universities%2COxford+and+Cambridge+University&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHarvard%20and%20Yale%20College%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHarvard%20and%20Yale%20Colleges%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COxford%20and%20Cambridge%20Universities%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COxford%20and%20Cambridge%20University%3B%2Cc0), although both usages are found.

Another reason to pluralize is so nobody thinks you're talking about a single University with a dual name, like "William and Mary College".

Answer (score 1):

This is a style question, and (as is so often the case) style advice varies from one style guide to another. Although the position that Peter Shor lays out in his answer makes perfect sense, *The Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003) reaches a different conclusion on the same point:

> INSTITUTIONS AND COMPANIES
>
> **8.73** *What to capitalize.* The full names of institutions and companies and of their departments, and sometimes their short forms, are capitalized. A *the* preceding a name, even when part of the official title is is lowercased in running text. ...
>
> [Relevant examples:] the University of Chicago; the university; the University of Chicago and Harvard University; **Northwestern and Princeton universities**; the University of Wisconsin–Madison

Chicago offers similar advice on topological divisions, by the way—for example, "the Pacific Ocean; The Pacific and Atlantic oceans," and "the Illinois River; the Illinois and the Chicago rivers."

This isn't to say that Chicago's style preference is right and Peter Shor's is wrong; it's to recall that style decisions are ultimately arbitrary and not grounded in a world of right-or-wrong choices. Once you commit to a style, there is time enough for errors of inconsistency; you don't have to fear being wrong from the get-go—unless you are required to obey the advice of a particular style guide.